# Want Stacked column highchart to represent data in two colomn

Tags: highcharts

i want to represent two categories of data in stacked column chart. Though i am able to get one column with stacks showing its sub category data.Below is the code i am trying

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

I want a chart which can full fill below mentioned requirement. I want to show month wise purchase of 4-wheeler(cars) and 2-wheeler(bikes and scooter) sale monthwise for example for month of october if we have data for cars as ford=25,Maruti=30,Honda=20,BMW=15 and for 2-wheeler Bajaj=70,Yamaha=60,Honda=40,Suzuki=10. Now i want my chart to show each 4-wheeler as one stacked column showing all its data(Ford,Maruti,Honda,BMW) as its stacks and same for 2-wheeler . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with grouped plugin, https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/ which seems to be solution of your problem. Let us know if it correct.